# How do I bring in only certain column/data field containing letter "A" into the pivot?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a vba that creates a pivot for a datasheet. However, I have been able to pull in the row fields correctly. I also am able to bring values for the columns for all the data however I want to filter to specific ones. Such bring in only ones that data header contains "GL" or "NT"

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim I As Long
For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
For I = 1 To pt.PivotFields.Count
    With pt.PivotFields(I)
        If .Orientation = 0 Then .Orientation = xlDataField
    End With
    Next
Next
```

instead of bringing in all the data, I would like for it to only bring in one that has header containing "GL" or "NT"

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  Did you mean to say that you "have" NOT "been able to pull in the row fields correctly"?  Also, your title talks about the letter "A" but your post refers to "GL" or "NT".  Finally, your code would not create a pivot table.  Are you wanting to add filters for the specific conditions to existing pivot tables? Please review site guidelines on [ask] and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then [edit] your post instead of adding information in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would only need to add another condition that checks the field name. Something like:

```
If .Orientation = 0 and (.Name like *GL* or .Name like *NT*) Then .Orientation = xlDataField
```